# Immutable.js with angular 2

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, immutable.js

**The correct way to use immutable.js with angular 2?**

My app works, i am trying to optimize and refactor to get performance out of the app. I have come across immutable.js and i want to change my data that is retrieved from an http request to immutable data then call it in an angular *ngFor loop.

The data returns if i do a console log, but when i try to map the data to an immutable object i get an object map, but how do i then access it. I see map->rout->entries->Array[]->Array[] my data is in the last array element.

```
// component.ts
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { List, Map } from 'immutable'; 
import * as Immutable from 'immutable'; 

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  templateUrl: './component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./component.css'],
})

export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  let myData:any = null;
  constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.callData("test.json");
  }

  callData(targetUrl) {
      return this.http.get(targetUrl))
      .map((res) => res.json())
      .subscribe(
        (data) => {
         this.myData = [];
         this.myData = Immutable.Map(data);
         console.log(data); // RETURNS THE DATA
         console.log(this.myData); // RETURNS MAP
      });
  }
}
// component.html
   <div *ngIf="myData != null">
       <div *ngFor="let key of myData; let i = index">
          <div class="someClass">
             {{myData[key].something}}
          </div>
       </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Immutable.js, you should access immutable ojbects or arrays using the `get` method.

In your template, do the following:
`{{myData.get(key).something}}`